# Compare with values in other columns within an Over row as a calculated column

Tags: spotfire

I have data with product numbers, process numbers, X coordinates, and Y coordinates.

The process numbers are text values such as 1000, 2000, and 3000, and each coordinate has X and Y values.

If i want to calculate the number of rows that meet the following criteria or concatenate them, where the process number is 2000 and within the range of +-20 on the X-axis and +-20 on the Y-axis, while the process number is 1000

if([Process Number]<>'2000',Null, Sum(if([Process Number]='1000' and [X]<(?+20) AND [X]>(?+20) AND [Y]<(?+20) AND [Y]>(?+20) ,1,0) OVER ([Product Number])

However, in this formula, the '?' part should also be applied based on the product number of the overlying row, which is causing the desired values not to appear.

The 'Moving Count' column is the value I want to get.

Among the rows with the value of "Process Number" calculating only 2000 and having the same "Product Number" of "Process Number" 1000 are candidates, and I would like to get the count of rows with the values of X and Y +-2 among them.

| Product Number | Process Number | X | Y | Margin as Property | Maching Count | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 9 | 16 | 2 | Null | Only calculate at 2000 |
| 1 | 2000 | 6 | 12 | 2 | 0 | Calculate only x and y of 1000 ±2 |
| 1 | 2000 | 2 | 19 | 2 | 0 | Calculate only x and y of 1000 ±2 |
| 1 | 3000 | 2 | 12 | 2 | Null | Only calculate at 2000 |
| 1 | 1000 | 7 | 16 | 2 | Null | Only calculate at 2000 |
| 1 | 2000 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 0 | Calculate only x and y of 1000 ±2 |
| 2 | 1000 | 2 | 7 | 2 | Null | Only calculate at 2000 |
| 2 | 2000 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 0 | Calculate only x and y of 1000 ±2 |
| 2 | 2000 | 6 | 5 | 2 | 0 | Calculate only x and y of 1000 ±2 |
| 2 | 2000 | 19 | 19 | 2 | 0 | Calculate only x and y of 1000 ±2 |
| 2 | 2000 | 2 | 8 | 2 | 1 | Calculate only x and y of 1000 ±2 |
| 2 | 1000 | 7 | 13 | 2 | Null | Only calculate at 2000 |
| 2 | 3000 | 5 | 7 | 2 | Null | Only calculate at 2000 |
| 3 | 3000 | 8 | 12 | 2 | Null | Only calculate at 2000 |
| 3 | 1000 | 14 | 3 | 2 | Null | Only calculate at 2000 |
| 3 | 1000 | 9 | 8 | 2 | Null | Only calculate at 2000 |
| 3 | 1000 | 4 | 6 | 2 | Null | Only calculate at 2000 |
| 3 | 2000 | 10 | 10 | 2 | 1 | Calculate only x and y of 1000 ±2 |
| 3 | 2000 | 12 | 4 | 2 | 1 | Calculate only x and y of 1000 ±2 |
| 3 | 2000 | 11 | 14 | 2 | 0 | Calculate only x and y of 1000 ±2 |